# laravel queue without DB query

Tags: laravel, asynchronous, queue, jobs

I want to minimize DB queries for an incoming request. It currently requires writes to 6 different tables. The processing does not need to be done before returning the response. 
I therefore consider laravel queues, but I wonder if I could also get rid of the separate query that is needed to write to the queue/jobs table. Can I store jobs locally instead of writing them to the DB?

One possible hack would be to have a separate route that I send the data to that does the processing. This way i would not need to write to the DB, but could rather just forward the data to that route without waiting for a response. Would this be faster than writing a job to the DB?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#driver-prerequisites

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use native queue driver (that is using DB) I can advised you to use Rabbit-MQ. here is a good driver implementation for Laravel:

[RabbitMQ Queue driver for Larave](https://github.com/vyuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq)

You will have to run deamon service in the CLI using:

`./artisan queue:work` (deamon version - after you made each change in code you will have to call `./artisan queue:restart` to refresh the code for queue)

or

`./artisan queue:listen` (for `./artisan queue:work --once` process productor)

or use [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/running.html) with:

`./artisan queue:work --once`

(my personal favourite)

After that each task you will put to queue (with `dispatch()` or `\Queue::push()`) will be delivered to RabbitMQ server and will be exectuted through the queue driver.